# form:select options value is same text as the options text

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to display inside a spring select element the parent table rows of a detail table. Here is the bean definition of the parent table :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "HR.DEPARTMENTS")
public class Dept {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT_NAME")
    private String dname;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "dept")
    @Transient
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>(0);

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDname() {
        return dname;
    }

    public void setDname(String dname) {
        this.dname = dname;
    }

    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return dname;
    }

}
```

The source of the spring select element is this List :

```
@Override
@Transactional
public List<Dept> list() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Dept> listDept = (List<Dept>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
    .createCriteria(Dept.class)
    .addOrder(Order.asc("dname"))
    .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();
    return listDept;
}
```

jsp is :

```
<form:select path="dept">
    <form:option value="" label="-- choose a department --"/>
    <form:options items="${depts}" />
</form:select>
```

At runtime when entering in update mode then the value of the select options are same as its texts !

So how to make the options value to be the **id** attribute value of the bean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<form:options>` is calling the toString() method on the `Dept` object in order to fill the `value` and the `name` of the html:option

As of the spring-form.tld, the definition of the `<form:options>` is like this:

```
<tag>
        <description>Renders a list of HTML 'option' tags. Sets 'selected' as appropriate
        based on bound value.</description>
        <name>options</name>
        <tag-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.OptionsTag</tag-class>
        <body-content>empty</body-content>
        <attribute>
            <description>HTML Standard Attribute</description>
            <name>id</name>
            <required>false</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <description>The Collection, Map or array of objects used to generate the inner
            'option' tags. This attribute is required unless the containing select's property
            for data binding is an Enum, in which case the enum's values are used.</description>
            <name>items</name>
            <required>false</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <description>Name of the property mapped to 'value' attribute of the 'option' tag</description>
            <name>itemValue</name>
            <required>false</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <description>Name of the property mapped to the inner text of the 'option' tag</description>
            <name>itemLabel</name>
            <required>false</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
```

So, you can configure the `<form:options>` in order to use the proper properties of the `Dept` you want to use as `id` and `value`:

```
<form:options items="${depts}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="dname" />
```